# Swap with variadic base classes

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I'm experimenting with writing a tuple, and one thing I haven't figured out is how to write a swap. The (simplified) types look like this:

```
template<size_t I, typename T>
struct tuple_elem {
    ...

    void swap(tuple_elem& other)
    {
        // implemented
    }
};

template<size_t... Is, typename... Ts>
struct tuple_impl<std::index_sequence<Is...>, Ts...>
    : private tuple_elem<Is, Ts>...
{
    void swap(tuple_impl& other)
    {
        // ???
    }
};
```

I've been trying to unpack the indices and types at the place marked by `// ???`, but can't for the life of me figure out how to. I've tried things like:

```
static_cast<tuple_elem<Is, Ts>&>(*this)->swap(
            static_cast<tuple_elem<Is, Ts>&>(other))...;
```

But was given errors like:

```
Tuple.hpp:182:64: error: expected ';' before '...' token
                 static_cast<tuple_elem<Is, Ts>&>(other))...;
                                                         ^~~
Tuple.hpp:182:67: error: parameter packs not expanded with '...':
                 static_cast<tuple_elem<Is, Ts>&>(other))...;
                                                            ^
```

Help!

Comment: Something like `swap(static_cast<tuple_elem<Is, Ts>(*this), static_cast<tuple_elem<Is, Ts>(other)), ...` perhaps? Maybe using a dummy array intializer.

Comment: @KerrekSB Ah, dummy array does the trick. But wondering if it can be done more elegantly…

Comment: In C++17 you have fold expressions, which make this very nice and readable.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, first of all. By expanding the pack the way you've tried, you are not going to get a valid expression. Try to write it out.

Now I'll start with the simplest. (I'm assuming you're implementing a tuple, so you have some of the standard utilities `std::tuple` has.) If your compiler implements C++17's fold expressions, a swap can be done as simple as:

```
template<typename... Tn, typename... Tn2, size_t... Is>
void swap_impl(tuple<Tn...>& a, tuple<Tn2...>& b, std::index_sequence<Is...>)
{
    using std::swap;
    (swap(get<Is>(a), get<Is>(b)), ...);
}
```

which is called with the two tuples and `std::index_sequence_for<Is...>{}`. `get<I>(tuple)` is easy to implement, it's your `static_cast<tuple_elem<Is, Ts>&>(tuple)` thing.

On the other hand if you only have access to C++14, my approach would look like this:

```
template<size_t N>
struct tuple_ops
{
    template<typename T, typename T2, size_t I = tuple_size<T>::value - N>
    static constexpr void swap(T& a, T2& b) 
    {
        using std::swap;
        swap(get<I>(a), get<I>(b));
        return tuple_ops<N - 1>::swap(a, b);
    }
};
```

Obviously as with any recursive method, you'd need to provide a base case for 0.

```
template<>
struct tuple_ops<0>
{
    template<typename T, typename T2>
    static constexpr void swap(T&, T2&) noexcept {}
};
```

Then your swap function would look like:

```
constexpr void swap(tuple& rhs) {
     tuple_ops<sizeof...(Tn)>::swap(*this, rhs);
}
```

Note: code is untested.